# Add a variable struct as payload inside a struct for sending via udp in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, struct

I'm currently working on a program where I'm designing my own protocol to send over UDP.

The format is as follows:

```
packet
 -packet type
 -payload
```

where the payload has a specific format based on the packet type. Two examples of packet types are `status_req` and `status_res`:

```
status_req
  -id

status_res
  -id
  -status_1
  -status_2
```

Does anyone have a smooth method to solve this both at the sender and receiver? My initial idea was struct. Then I'm able to send and receive the packet type, but I'm not able to figure out a good way to implement the variable payload.

A good start would be to know which data type payload should be and how to convert for example status_req to payload on the sender side and payload to status_req on the receiver side.

Comment: C++ does not have variable sized `struct`s.  Size of all objects are fixed at compile time. Use a char / unsigned char buffer to read/write the data and `std::memcpy` to/from it to avoid Undefined Behaviour.  Also if asking a language tagged question you should post a [mcve] or reference to a part of the Standard etc,

Comment: Maybe [Google Protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) could help here...

Comment: what you send across the network is just a stream of bytes. The receiver reads `packet type` and knows how to interpret those bytes, it either deserializes a `status_req` or a `status_res`. Serialization is a wide topic and not trivial to get right, you might want to use an existing library

Comment: [Flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) was originally created at Google for game development and other performance-critical applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! After some thinking, I realized that I can make it simple and just convert everything to a comma separated string and convert it back in the other end. Both ends know the protocol. Any pitfalls I should be aware of?